# How to retrieve data from a PHP server in android by primery key of a table in textview

Tags: php, android

I want to parse this data to `dataread.php` and want to fetch some data from a PHP server by roll no...

I want to retrieve data from PHP and display it in text views in android. I have written some code below, but it does not work.

Please help me. Thanks for your support in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity(
    TextView result;
    EditText roll;
    Button search;
    Editable data;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        roll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollnumber);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                data = roll.getText();

                getSqlDetails();
            }
        });
    }
    private void getSqlDetails(){

        String url = "http://192.168.0.1/data/readdata.php?roll_no="+ data;
        pd.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        pd.hide();


                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                                String id = jsonobject.getString("REGISTRATION_NO");
                                String stu = jsonobject.getString("STU_NAME").trim();
                                String fa = jsonobject.getString("FA_NAME").trim();
                                String mo = jsonobject.getString("MO_NAME").trim();
                                String eng = jsonobject.getString("ENG_TOTAL").trim();
                                String math = jsonobject.getString("MATH_TOTAL").trim();
                                String it = jsonobject.getString("IT_TOTAL").trim();
                                String pmo = jsonobject.getString("PMO_TOTAL").trim();
                                String pspc = jsonobject.getString("PSPC_TOTAL").trim();
                                String itlab = jsonobject.getString("IT_LAB_TOTAL").trim();
                                String pspclab = jsonobject.getString("PSPC_LAB_TOTAL").trim();
                                String total = jsonobject.getString("TOTAL_MARKS").trim();
                                String sgpa = jsonobject.getString("SGPA").trim();
                                String cgpa = jsonobject.getString("CGPA").trim();


                                result.setText("\t\t\t                    B.C.A 1ST SEM 2016\n \n Registration no. -" + id+"\n Student name -" + stu +"\n Father name -"+fa+"\n Mother Name -"+mo+"\n English Total -"+eng
                                        +"\n Math Total -"+math+"\n It Total -"+it+"\n Pmo Total -"+pmo+"\n Pspc Total -"+pspc+"\n It lab -"+itlab+"\n Pspc lab -"+pspclab
                                        +"\n Total Marks -"+total+"\n Sgpa -"+sgpa+"\n Cgpa -"+cgpa);




                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error != null) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

        );

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Volley to do this. I could explain this but it is a very long little bit. Basically you have to create a connector in PHP upload it to your server and then connect the android app to it using Volley library.

But here is a tutorial on it. This should get you started:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-mysql-database-android/

Comment: data fetch but not by specific id which i give in my edittext ,i want to fetch data only user enter  there unique id.and i all ready used volley in  my project

Comment: Ok so its time to start debugging! LOL. What is happening when you send the data to the url param. Is it returning the data? What does your connection file look like that your sending this data to? Let me know I will replicat the code locally and try to help you out if I can. I like debugging LOL.